# Microsoft Outlook Addon

Tags: outlook, add-in

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System can only be installed on a machine with the corresponding Visual Studio localized edition. Please install the matching Visual Studio 2005 localized edition and then run Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System setup again.

Comment: I am running vstor.exe on window 7 and get erro.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of interest: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/a3fecb4c-084c-4901-a694-b1ab75863414